# Subtracting the mean from the values of an array with Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have an np array `arr` and I want to substract the mean of this array `mean_arr` from the values of my array `arr`.

I am using :

```
arr = df.values
mean_arr = df.mean()
arr_new = [(y - mean_arr) for y in df.values]
```

It does calculate but it takes a long time to do it and the output is an array of arrays that have the same value:

```
[array([a,a,a]), array([b,b,b]) ...]
```

There is something wrong with my way off calculating. There is any other way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `arr - arr.mean(-1,keepdims=1)` should solve it.

Comment: Thank you @Divakar, it works. I am sorry, I didn't see tha duplicate of the question since they don't talk about mean in the title, it didn't appear to me when I was searching.

Comment: That's okay really. The search on here isn't the best.